# Execute all functions in a logical operation

Tags: php, boolean-logic

I have two functions `a()` and `b()`, both return a Boolean. I know that evaluation of logical expressions is stopped as soon as the result is known, but is there a way to perform a logical operation on two or more functions in such a manner that both functions execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment on the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#90386)

> Evaluation of logical expressions is stopped as soon as the result is known.
>   If you don't want this, you can replace the and-operator by min() and the or-operator by max().

So this code may be of use to you, as you can see *all* functions are called in each case and, yes, you can use this with more than two functions:-

```
function a()
{
    echo "function a<br/>\n";
    return true;
}
function b()
{
    echo "function b<br/>\n";
    return false;
}

function c()
{
    echo "function c<br/>\n";
    return false;
}

echo min(a(), b(), c());
echo "<br/>";
echo max(a(), b(), c());
echo "<br/>";
```

Output:-

```
function a
function b
function c
(false)    
function a
function b
function c
(true)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CgXJo)

Comment: That's very pretty solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need, this **may** be possible (following @JakobPogulis 's answer):

PHP:

```
function a() {
    print("A");
    return true;
}

function b() {
    print("B");
    return false;
}
var_dump((boolean)(intval(a()) | intval(b())));
var_dump((boolean)(intval(a()) & intval(b())));
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/lmR1L)

JavaScript:

```
function a()
{
    console.log("A");
    return true;
}
function b()
{
    console.log("B");
    return false;
}
console.log(Boolean(Number(a()) & Number(b())));
console.log(Boolean(Number(a()) | Number(b())));
```

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LzhaP/)

Comment: You should expand on why it only "may" be possible.  In what case is it not possible?

Comment: @Mash I don't know, I wasn't quite sure if this is what OP want (question was closed and edited and re-opened).

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is that both functions should be executed, it is not possible to guarantee this behavior with a single statement. At first you might think that a conjunction or disjunction could be used, but both of those constructions are *lazy* which means that they will stop the evaluation as soon as they are known to be true (for disjunction) or false (for conjunction).

```
function a() {
    print("A");
    return true;
}

function b() {
    print("B");
    return false;
}

$disjunction = a() || b(); // prints A, not B
$conjunction = b() && a(); // prints B, not A
```

The above code would only output `AB`, and not `ABBA` as you might expect. This is because a disjunction will always be true when one value is true, and a conjunction will always be false when one value is false.

**Addition**

If this behavior is really required for some reason, PHP functions like `map`, `reduce` and `filter` could be use to evaluate several statements and end up with a single boolean answer. Although this would require you to create additional functions to support the evaluation (which could be used with the `create_function` function) and wont be nearly as readable as using multiple lines and a lot harder to debug if it would come to that.

Comment: That's exactly the case. So there is no other way than calling every single functions in separate expression, getting their returns and then making disjunction. That's really sad

Comment: @BlaskPoranka, I've added some additional notes as to how this behavior could be enforced, although unless this behavior is required because of some dynamic constructions or evaluation based on user input I would really advice against it.

Comment: Yes, I was doing `!array_filter(array(a(), b(), c()))` in the first place but I didn't like it. Please see @vascowhite answer it's very elegant :)

Answer (score -3):

You mean something like the following?

```
var bothTrue;

if(a() && b()) {
    bothTrue = true;
}
else {
    bothTrue = false;
}
```

Or what do you mean specifically by "alternative"?

Comment: This could be written as a single line `var bothTrue = a() && b();` to increase readability, also, this answer doesn't mention lazy operations at all which seems to be the main problem of this question.